# Belongs to with different method name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a bit of a problem with Rails. I have two models: `Product` & `Category`. Now a product has one category.

So I assumed I would just put a `belongs_to` in the class and be done with it but due to the weird table layout I've inherited the `category_id` column is called `category`. So I aliased the attribute as `category_id` and done `belongs_to :category` but it just returns nil. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you simply rename this column?

Comment: Sadly not. With 1000+ records and an entire legacy system that uses that column name I value my sanity more than to attempt that haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
belongs_to :product_category, foreign_key: :category, class_name: "Category"
```